# Powershell command to open Powershell Remotely Via Keyboard

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open PowerShell remotely via using send-key. I am not able to fire up the run prompt using Win key. Can someone help here. Opening Teamviewer first and then activating the window and trying to open PS via command prompt .Below is the snippet

```
    Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
    $wshell.AppActivate('Teamviewer')
    $wshell.SendKeys("Windows{R}")
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    $wshell.SendKeys('PowerShell')
```

Comment: First, why? Jus curious. Are your targets machines you own / manage? Otherwise, this sounds a bit sketchy. 8^}  ... 2nd, what are you not just using PSRemoting vs literally and RDP session? Windows does have user identity boundaries, the prevent certain actions. You cannot run PoSH natively as the identity of a user on a remote machine, well you can with SysInternals' PSExec or AutoIt, but that is a different deal. What do you need to do interactively, that you can't do via a remote session?

Comment: Answer to your question is i dont have servers communication from local and between each other due to security reasons so i am using Team Viewer to take the sessions. That is why i am looking for keyword for Window button to open command prompt and type powershell for next script execution. Hope that makes sense.